# call identification authority is closed after app updated in ios10?

Tags: ios, callkit

I used callkit   to identify  in coming call of  my own company,it work well,but when users update the app ,the authority of call indentification is closed by deafault again,whitch was opend by users before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to the user giving the app permission in iOS settings being disabled after app updates, this was a bug that is definitely fixed in 10.1.